# Javascript Performance

Tags: javascript, performance

I would like to evaluate the execution time of the processes contained in a javascript function, so I created a simple code that can evaluate this.

I would like your opinion as experts and know if I can use the code to evaluate the execution time of much more complex processes.

I tried it on IE, FF and Chrome, and Chrome processes were faster.

[LINK TO THE EXPERIMENT](http://jsfiddle.net/cimadelmundo/xuzwe6ch/)

This is my Javascript:

```
/* Global Vars */
var inputSearch = document.getElementById('texto');
var buscando = document.getElementById('buscando');

/* TIME PERFORMANCE > Catching */
var timer = document.getElementById('timer');
var maxtimer = document.getElementById('maxtimer');
var qmaxtimer = document.getElementById('querymaxtimer');

/* Adding Event */    
if(window.addEventListener)
{inputSearch.addEventListener('keyup',searching,false);}
else
{if(window.attachEvent){inputSearch.attachEvent('keyup',searching);}}

/* Test Function */
function searching(event,callback)
{

    /* TIME PERFORMANCE */
    /* >> Timer Ini */  
    var i = performance.now();

    /* Do something........ */
    var query = this.value;
    buscando.textContent = query;
    /* Finish something ......... */

    /* TIME PERFORMANCE */
    /* >> Timer End */  
    var f = performance.now();
    /* >> TotalTime */  
    var totalTime = f - i;
    var t;
    if(totalTime < 1){
        if(totalTime<=0.0001){t= ' Nanoseconds?';}
        else{t= ' Microseconds';}
    }else{t = ' Miliseconds'};

    /* >> Max Time   */  
    var mt = parseFloat(maxtimer.textContent);         
    if(totalTime > mt){
        maxtimer.textContent = totalTime.toFixed(15) + t; 
        qmaxtimer.textContent=query;
    }

    /* >> Current Time   */ 
    timer.textContent = totalTime.toFixed(15) + t;
}
```

Thank you.

P.D.: Sorry for my bad english :-)

Comment: http://jsperf.com/

Comment: http://benchmarkjs.com/

Comment: https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/cpu-profiling

Answer (score 0):

These kind of measurements can never be truly achieved via editing the code. First of all, it might be too difficult to just edit each and every method in your code to add those timing calls, secondly, you might be breaking stuff in the process.

I would suggest you to use the Performance tools present in both Firefox and Chrome, via these, you can measure time spent in various parts of your code along with the bottlenecks etc.

You can also see where your UI froze, and what code was super efficient.

Firefox : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Profiler
Chrome : https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/timeline